# How to create HTTP POST request with libmicrohttpd/microhttpd

Tags: c++, c

I am using libmicrohttpd library and I need to send POST request with one string parameter in body. Can anyone show me how to create POST request with libmicrohttpd ( I am Java guy and this C++ is kinda strange to me ) ?

Answer (score 2):

libmicrohttpd is a library to develop servers. Creating requests is done by clients, and therefore outside the scope of libmicrohttpd.

You might want to look into [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) for client functionality.

Comment: I downloaded curl and put in my project ( in curl directory in VS ) all files from include/curl folder but I got error in curlrules.h CURL_SIZEOF_LONG definition is missing. Is this right way to add curl to my project ?